# Specific Ethernet ports not working

Tags: networking, ethernet, macbook-air

I own a MacBook Air 2017.

In my house I have 12 Ethernet ports for wired internet.

All I have to do is connect my router to the suitable input and then connect my Apple computer to the relevant port.

I use the exact same cables for connecting on all the ports. The problem is two ports do not work, but yesterday it did work.

I have run diagnostics and everything. The only difference of those ports is that they are upside down like so:

[image: ports]

Everything else is the same. Does it matter that they are upside down? Is there something that I am missing? Should I be doing something that I am not? Thank you for the help.

Comment: No, "upside down" cannot affect on working ability. I think it's any inner damage (wrong contacts and so on).

Comment: Please confirm operation by using a simple switch and short patch cables at either end of the link.